# Sharepoint list: Unable to populate field using variable value

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, jsom, form

I am trying to populate the list column with calculated value in code below.

While the alert & messages show the value being assigned to variable correctly but somehow field is not getting populated with that value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clientContext = null;
    var web = null;
    var count = null;
    var list ;
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Initialize, "sp.js");
    function Initialize()
    {
        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = clientContext.get_web();
        list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Data Setup");
        clientContext.load(list);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
    }
    function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
       var count = list.get_itemCount();
        alert("Total item count in the list: " + count);
               var AutoIncremental = "MAA-SR-" + count;
               $("input[title^='*Request ID*']").val(AutoIncremental);
               $("input[title^='*Request ID*']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think the issue is with your jquery selector for the input field. Can you please share the screenshot of HTML of input field by inspecting this element? I will suggest you the better selector for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution using JQuery**:

Have you referenced jQuery file in your code (I suspect you haven't)? If Yes then below code should work for you:

```
$("input[title^='Request ID']").val(AutoIncremental);
```

If you have not referenced JQuery file then you can refer it like below in your HTML and then use same code as above:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Recommended is to download jQuery file, upload it in your SharePoint site and then refer it's URL in `src` attribute by replacing the web CDN link.

**Solution using JavaScript**:

If you don't want to use JQuery then you can achieve the same using plain JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector("input[title^='Request ID']").value = AutoIncremental;
document.querySelector("input[title^='Request ID']").disabled = "disabled";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the asterisk characters around the `Request ID` as the below. It should work for you.

```
$("input[title^='Request ID']").val(AutoIncremental);
$("input[title^='Request ID']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: I changed it as below but still no luck, it's not even giving me the second alert, is something wrong with syntax ? ```function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
       var count = list.get_itemCount();
               var AutoIncremental = "FAM-SDSR-" + count;
               //alert(AutoIncremental);
               $("input[title^='Request ID']").val(AutoIncremental);
               $("input[title^='Request ID']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
               alert("X  "+ AutoIncremental);
    } ```